# How to use Ng2 Bootstrap TypeAhead value from model and not the one from popup?

Tags: angular, typeahead, angular2-forms, ng2-bootstrap

NG2-Bootstrap TypeAhead offers:

```
[typeaheadOptionField]="'view'"
```

to use from a JSON like

```
{id: 1, name: 'Alabama', view:'State: Alabama'}
```

a specific value shown in popup. This value is also taken if pressing Enter. But what if I want to use another value from the backing JSON (like "name" above)? Implementing

```
 (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelectZip($event)"
```

does not help since if I write the value here to the model this is not considered since Ng2-Bootstrap overwrites this afterwards with the one from the popup again.